# What suffix should I use to define UInt128 in F#?

Tags: f#

How to define UInt128 value in F#, what suffix should I use?
For UInt64 it is UL
let num = 1UL

I can define let num128: UInt128 = 1UL but exact suffix would be better.

Why would I need 220 characters to ask this question ))

Comment: There are libraries, even MIT licensed, that may be of help dealing with the two 128 bit types, but I'm not familiar with any of these libraries.

Answer (score 3):

The F# literal types are defined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/literals), and there is no UInt128 literal.
I am afraid you will have to use one of the other integer literal types. Bigint may be interesting for you.